# How to use regex or preg_match in PHP to extract exact parts of a string as a variables?

Tags: php

```
echo(addslashes($dataItem->calculation));
Returns:
"if(([item-237_isChecked])){(2350)} 
if(([item-238_isChecked])){(3000)}
if(([item-236_isChecked])&&([item-242_isChecked])){(1090)}
if(([item-236_isChecked])&&([item-243_isChecked])){(2860)} 
if(([item-239_isChecked])){(4000)}"
```

`$dataItem->calculation` comes from the database.

I am trying to extract the values `(2350,3000,1090,2860,4000)` as separate variables (those values can change, so I want to match anything for example

between

`if(([item-237_isChecked])){(`

and

`")}"
).`

Did a bunch of testing, but didn't succeed:

```
$calculationString1 = preg_match('/if(([item-237_isChecked])){((.*?))}/', addslashes($dataItem->calculation));
```

UPDATE:
I solved the problem by simplifying my input with `explode()`:

```
    $somestring1 = explode(PHP_EOL, addslashes($dataItem->calculation));

    $somesubstring1 = explode('{',$somestring1[0]);
    $somesubstring2 = explode('{',$somestring1[1]);
    $somesubstring3 = explode('{',$somestring1[2]);
    $somesubstring4 = explode('{',$somestring1[3]);
    $somesubstring5 = explode('{',$somestring1[4]);


    preg_match('/[0-9]{1,6}+/', $somesubstring3[1], $singlelongprice1);
    preg_match('/[0-9]{1,6}+/', $somesubstring4[1], $singlewidelongprice1);
    preg_match('/[0-9]{1,6}+/', $somesubstring1[1], $doublelongprice1);
    preg_match('/[0-9]{1,6}+/', $somesubstring2[1], $triplelongprice1);
    preg_match('/[0-9]{1,6}+/', $somesubstring5[1], $quodlongprice1);

    $singlelongprice = implode($singlelongprice1);
    $singlewidelongprice = implode($singlewidelongprice1);
    $doublelongprice = implode($doublelongprice1);
    $triplelongprice = implode($triplelongprice1);
    $quodlongprice = implode($quodlongprice1);
```

Comment: Thanks these helped, but I still couldn't quite make a nice regex to match what I need, so I simplified the problem as shown in the update

Comment: Please can you post your solution as a separate answer and then make it the "approved" answer for this question? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like isolating your targeted digital strings doesn't require matching the right-side `)}` so I am omitting that part from my pattern.  I am matching `{(`, then restarting the fullstring match with `\K`, then matching the consecutive digits.

After checking if `preg_match_all()` makes exactly 5 matches, I assign the 5 fullstring matches (`[0]` is the fullstring matches subarray), and assign them to variables using the modern technique of array deconstructing -- this can be replace with the less-modern `list()` call.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/NKW3i))

```
$data = 'if(([item-237_isChecked])){(2350)} 
if(([item-238_isChecked])){(3000)}
if(([item-236_isChecked])&&([item-242_isChecked])){(1090)}
if(([item-236_isChecked])&&([item-243_isChecked])){(2860)} 
if(([item-239_isChecked])){(4000)};';

[$singlelongprice1, $singlewidelongprice1, $doublelongprice1, $triplelongprice1, $quadlongprice1] = preg_match_all('~{\(\K\d+~', $data, $matches) == 5 ? $matches[0] : ['','','','',''];

echo '$singlelongprice1 = ' , $singlelongprice1 , "\n";
echo '$singlewidelongprice1 = ' , $singlewidelongprice1 , "\n";
echo '$doublelongprice1 = ' , $doublelongprice1 , "\n";
echo '$triplelongprice1 = ' , $triplelongprice1 , "\n";
echo '$quadlongprice1 = ' , $quadlongprice1;
```

Output:

```
$singlelongprice1 = 2350
$singlewidelongprice1 = 3000
$doublelongprice1 = 1090
$triplelongprice1 = 2860
$quadlongprice1 = 4000
```

p.s. I changed `quod` to `quad`.  Whenever you need to develop a regex pattern, run your tests @ https://regex101.com like this: https://regex101.com/r/31pNLa/1